# Trying to get pip onto UnixWare

Tags: unix, ftp, python, scp, pip

I have an installation of *UnixWare 7.1.4* for which I'd like to add (python's) `pip`.

I know that `get-pip.py` is at `https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py`

My problem is that the only tools I have to get files from the internet are `scp,` `ftp,` and `lynx.` `Lynx` would do the job, unfortunately, the `lynx` I have does not support *https* connections.

I failed to find `get-pip.py` on an ftp server somewhere.

### **Any ideas how to get `pip` onto my ancient UnixWare?**

**Note:**

I have a working *Python 2.7.10* on that *UnixWare 7.1.4* (built from a tarball).

Answer (score 0):

Download the `get-pip.py` without https:

```
http://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py
```

works just fine.

Comment: Download with which command? Lynx doesn't even start when I try `lynx http://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py` in UnixWare. BTW, I gave up and created (in Linux/Windows) an ISO containing just _get-pip.py_, mounted that ISO, and thus managed to install `pip.`

Comment: It worked for me just fine using `lynx http://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py` downloaded the file. The problem will be somewhere else.